# Connect WiFi Manager from separate AsyncTask class in Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an application that uses an `AsyncTask` to connect to WiFi using `WifiManager`.
Now, I am using this in my `MainActivity` class as

```
public class connectWifi extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public connectWifi(MyActivity activity) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setMessage("Connecting to WiFi. Please Wait.");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        connected = true;
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo conn = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence wifi_on = "Connected to " + conn.getSSID();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast responseToast = Toast.makeText(context, wifi_on, duration);
        responseToast.show();
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

Now, I have another class `AlarmReceiver` which gets called via a `Broadcast`.  I am performing some network based action in that class which needs me to connect to WiFi first.
How can I create a separate class for `connectWifi` which does not involve first running `MainActivity`?
The issue I am facing is in creating the `Context` object which says `Non-static 'getApplicationContext()' cannot be referenced from static context`.
The same issue is with `getSystemService()`. How can I create this class as needed?

---

`abc` is the `AsyncTask` class.
`AlarmReceiver` is the `BroadcastReceiver`

My current flow of control is as follows:
START PROCEDURE
 - `AlarmManager` receives `Broadcast`
 - `AlarmManager` calls `enableWifi()` in `abc`
 - `enableWifi()` connects to WiFi
 - `AlarmManager` checks for connection state
 - `AlarmManager` then calls `new abc().execute("DATA1")`
 - `abc` then performs the `doInBackground` task (network request)
 - `AlarmManager` calls `disableWifi()` in `abc` to end WiFi
END PROCEDURE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separated class that depends on `Context`. Both `Activity` and a `BroadcastReceiver` can provide a `Context` to this class.

`Activity` is a subclass of `Context`, so you can pass the `Activity` as parameter.
And the first parameter of `onReceive` from `BroadcastReceiver` is the `Context`.

So you can create an class that receives an `Context` instance an use the `WifiManager`:

```
// This can run outside UI Thread
public static void enableWifi(Context context) {
   WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
   wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
}

// This must run on UI Thread
public static void verifyWifi(Context context) {
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo conn = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
    CharSequence wifi_on = "Connected to " + conn.getSSID();
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

    Toast.makeText(context, wifi_on, duration).show();
}
```

You can use this class to detect when `Wifi` is enabled or change it's state.

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Static Listener, you can change this
    static OnNetworkConnectionChangedListener mListener;

    // Service to check if Wifi is connected or not
    ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(mListener != null) {
            if(mConnectivityManager == null) {
                mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            }
            mListener.onConnectionChanged(NetworkStatusHelper.getConnectivityStatus(mConnectivityManager) != NetworkStatusHelper.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        return NetworkStatusHelper.getConnectivityStatus((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)) != NetworkStatusHelper.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
    }

    public static void setOnNetworkConnectionChangedListener(OnNetworkConnectionChangedListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnNetworkConnectionChangedListener {
        public void onConnectionChanged(boolean connected);
    }
}
```

With this you i'll need to require the `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And you i'll need to add a `receiver` for `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` and `WIFI_STATE_CHANGED`

```
<receiver
    android:name="yourpackage.NetworkChangeReceiver"
    android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

With this you can track when `Wifi` change its connectivity and is connected.

Comment: Okay, the application works now. But the issue is that it starts `enableWifi()` but does not wait till it is connected before sending the request. I put in a `Thread.sleep()` in my `enableWifi()` but that won't help, I guess. How can I fix that?

Comment: I think you must register an `BroadcastReceiver` to listen when `Wifi` is connected. I'll include some code to help you to start this. Wait a minute.

Comment: I am using `ConnectivityManager` to check if WiFi is connected. Let me try that route in the meanwhile.

Comment: And this `BroadcastReceiver` would get fired just after I call `enableWifi()` right?  
So I check for this within my `AlarmReceiver` class?

Comment: It's not accurate how much time will take to Wifi connect, i don't know if it's a good idea to wait for it in `AlarmReceiver` using `Thread.sleep`. So you can let `AlarmReceiver` implements `OnNetworkConnectionChangedListener`. Add `AlarmReceiver` using `setOnNetworkConnectionChangedListener` on `NetworkChangeReceiver` to wait Wifi to connect, and continue with your flow.

Comment: I shall try that ASAP.